# how to clear a textbox value in asp.net using a script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox in my asp.net that accepts different values, I wrote a script that every time I press F5 button,the values in textboxes be cleaned.When I run the code and press F5,the textboxes values exist. How can I solve this?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="wellDesigned0428._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="body">
            <div class="content ">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtCodePers" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtCodePers_TextChanged" MaxLength="4" ></asp:TextBox> 
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>   
        </div>
    </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.onkeydown = fkey;
            document.onkeyup = fkey;
            document.onkeypress = fkey;
            function fkey(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 116) {
                    alert("f5 pressed");
                    document.getElementById("txtCodePers").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("txtName").value = "";
                }
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Once the page loaded, what is the id for txtCodePers, check using view source

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the id that you are using txtCodePers, it's the id from server side. Either set the clientid or check what is the id for the txtCodePers using vew source.

More than this, I would not recommend you to override the default behavior of f5 which is refresh. What if user users mouse? or uses the browser button for refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The `ClientID` of your `TextBox` is not the same as given in the `ID`-property. So your javascript will not find the elements.

You can either use the `ClientID` in your script or in your simple case add the `ClientIDMode`-property to your textboxes:

`ClientIDMode="Static"`

This will result in the same `ClientID` as your `ID` and you don't have to change your javascript.